SwiftUI removing AnyView and decoupling specific types
So i have a view that takes viewModel containing array of elements providing views to build body in ForEach
And it looks like this:
struct MainTabView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TabViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(viewModel.tabs, id: \.title) { tab in
                tab.view
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: tab.imageName)
                        Text(tab.title)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Home")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

class TabViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabs: [TabItem] = [
        TabItem(title: "Home", imageName: "house.fill", view: AnyView(HomeView()))
    ]
}

struct TabItem {
    let title: String
    let imageName: String
    let view: AnyView
}

So I am trying to figure out a proper way to decouple our views from concrete types and also not use AnyView. But other then code above I could not come up with compilable code or find any helpful solution online.
Please can anyone explain to me the way to go abut concrete types, and dependency injection in SwiftUI in context of above code?
I tried to use protocols like:
protocol TabViewProviding {
    var title: String { get }
    var imageName: String { get }
    var tabView: any View { get }
}

protocol TabViewModelProviding: ObservableObject {
    var tabs: [TabViewProviding] { get }
}

and replace concrete types with generics but best i got was errors like
Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Content' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'
or just coupling concrete types in different places.
#edit
so given @lorem ipsum comment I guess this is the best approach:
struct MainTabView<ViewModel: TabViewModelProviding>: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(viewModel.tabs, id: \.title) { tab in
                createTabFor(tabType: tab.type)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: tab.imageName)
                        Text(tab.title)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func createTabFor(tabType: TabType) -> some View {
        switch tabType {
        case .recipes:
            RecipeListView()
        case .settings:
            SettingsView()
        }
    }
}

protocol TabViewModelProviding: ObservableObject {
    var tabs: [TabItemProviding] { get }
}

class TabViewModel: TabViewModelProviding {
    @Published var tabs: [TabItemProviding] = [
        TabItem(title: "Recipes", imageName: "wineglass.fill", type: .recipes),
        TabItem(title: "Settings", imageName: "gearshape.fill", type: .settings)
    ]
}

enum TabType {
    case settings
    case recipes
}

protocol TabItemProviding {
    var title: String { get }
    var imageName: String { get }
    var type: TabType { get }
}

struct TabItem: TabItemProviding {
    let title: String
    let imageName: String
    let type: TabType
}

Unless someone else can point out some improvement that would be it

Views don’t belong in models and SwiftUI does not work well with existentials. SwiftUI can adapt to models but shouldn’t be included within them. You should also not put views in arrays, SwiftUI is value based and has its own storage so it just makes copies of the views

So as per @lorem ipsum comment response "Views don’t belong in models and SwiftUI does not work well with existentials. SwiftUI can adapt to models but shouldn’t be included within them. You should also not put views in arrays, SwiftUI is value based and has its own storage so it just makes copies of the views"
And question edit already contains an approach.

Just FYI this point is further cemented by the newest tools released yesterday, we finally get access to individual views for UI Changes using a ForEach and ViewBuilder. ViewBuilder requires “some” vs “any”
